# New design bug on Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Just to report a styling issue regarding the new design.

On Firefox only, the badges are not properly aligned with the badges count.

[image]

Compared to Google Chrome where it's properly aligned

[image]

In case @Marius' comment is missed:

> Same thing happens on Chrome on Android phones when requesting the
>   "desktop view"

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but the same thing happens on chrome on android phones when requesting the "desktop view".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been corrected. This issue arose because I was using `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`, which I've come to learn are not ready for implementation (according to the W3C). Still [all major browsers *except Firefox and Opera Mini*](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-position-x) seem to accept the properties.

[image]

Sigh.

Anyway this has been corrected and badge icons are now correctly positioned in Firefox.